# Cancel OpenSSL RSA key generation via command line

Tags: encryption, openssl, tools

I'm running `macOS 10.12.1` with `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`

When generating an [RSA key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) with the [OpenSSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL) cli you are prompted to enter your passphrase.

With most command-line interfaces pressing `C-d` or `C-c` will exit the process; however, with openssl it seems like it's impossible to exit the program once you've started the key generation process.

Shown below is a session where I'm trying `C-c` and `C-d`, only after entering `foobar` twice do I exit:

```
$ openssl genrsa -aes128 -out fd.key 2048
Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus
.........+++
.................................................+++
e is 65537 (0x10001)
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
73496:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:850:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
73496:error:28069065:lib(40):UI_set_result:result too small:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-64/src/crypto/ui/ui_lib.c:850:You must type in 4 to 1023 characters
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
Verifying - Enter pass phrase for fd.key:
```

- How do I exit the `genrsa` openssl command?

Comment: I can reproduce that. Maybe you want to file a bug report?

Comment: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3076

Comment: They probably didn't get that you have to enter the password twice beforehand. I can't even close it with `SIGQUIT` as suggested.